# Haskell - What data structure to use for a sparse matrix multiply?

Tags: haskell

Using Haskell, I am doing exercises on HackerRank in order to familiarize myself with the language. For the [particular problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/stitch-the-torn-wiki) I am currently doing, I will have to do a matrix multiply. Unlike in Python where I could just use Numpy, I've checked on Ideone and it seems Haskell does not have any linear algebra packages plugged in, so I am going to do it by hand. If I was doing this problem in F# I would just use a plain array, but in Haskell I am not sure as it has various array classes. I am looking for some advice on what I should be looking into here as I have a total of three days experience in the language so far.

I am also wondering whether tuples are stack or heap allocated in Haskell as I might have to use them to encode `(index,value)` positions.

Comment: CSR format for the matrix, [`vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) for the vector.

Comment: Unfortunately, `vector` is not a part of the standard library. Ideone does not have it either, so I can't use that one.

Comment: That leaves you with [`Array`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/).

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic, `vector` isn't in the standard, but it's pretty dang important. Why do you need Ideone?

Comment: Ideone is the backend HackerRank uses. If Ideone does not support it then probably HackerRank doesn't either, though I should have checked the import on a HackerRank problem. I am still working on the problem at any rate, so I'll do so.

Comment: Well, if NumPy is supported then it would certainly be “fair” if `vector` were too, at the very least; it is basically the Haskell equivalent of NumPy. In fact it's rather more basic; NumPy is almost like [`hmatrix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix).

Comment: I've tested it and it seems HackerRank does support `vector` after all. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic Hackerrank does not use Ideone to compile and run your code. To know more about the machines and environment you can check this page: https://www.hackerrank.com/environment

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic Can you self answer this question, now that you have realized it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, the goto class in Haskell for plain arrays would be the [`Data.Vector.Unboxed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html). Haskell has a distinction between boxed and unboxed arrays, and even though I knew that it still somehow surprised me that in a vector of vectors, the outer vector would have to be a boxed type.

Also regarding tuples, per documentation for efficiency a vector of tuples will get compiled as tuple of vectors which definitely means that the elements will get allocated to a contiguous area on the heap.